Strange fail in AppleScript for PowerPoint
Why does this
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
     set selected_shapes to shape range of selection of active window
     log count of selected_shapes
     set selected_slides to slide range of selection of active window
     log count of selected_slides
end tell

fail at line 5 but not at line 3?
Message is:
iterate_through_selected_slides.applescript:216:240: execution error: Microsoft PowerPoint got an error: Can’t get active window. (-1728)

which is hugely puzzling, especially (additional info) since it does not fail if only one slide is selected, but does if there is more than one selected slide.

Some random thoughts: • We don't know what values are assigned to your variables. • In general, powerpoint uses 'presentation' rather than 'document' (or 'window'). • Things have to be handled differently when you have a single item versus a list of items. • Finally, error -1728 typically means that the item in question doesn't exist… for example item 3 of a two-item list.

I downloaded an unactivated copy of PowerPoint (which is almost literally good for nothing — I can't even type a slide title), but it let me run your script, which worked perfectly fine. Is the color-coding of the two 'set…' lines the same? ('selection' and '… range' in blue, 'active window' in purple, etc?) add in a log active window command right before the problem line and see what happens.

@TedWrigley wow - that's what I call tenacity. Thanks. Did you try to select 2 slides? It works fine when one selects a single slide, but fails when two slides are selected

Like I said, unactivated PowerPoint is almost literally good for nothing. I can't make second slide. It validates everything I've always thought about Microsoft.

@simone: I managed to open an old multi-slide ppt file and ran your script, which did not crash. However, when I added this line to your script: log (get properties of selection of active window) I noticed two things. (1) selections seem to come in 'types' so it may only get a shape range when the selection is a 'shape' type selection. (2) no matter what I did all of the 'range' properties returned 'missing value'. This means (a) the UA version I'm using is borked, (b) the PP implementation is borked, or (c) my brain is borked.

@TedWrigley I suspect it's (b)
